# Error: No sql_connection parameter is established when creating instances on openstack pike devstack

Tags: openstack, sqlconnection, openstack-nova, devstack, openstack-horizon

I've successfully installed Openstack Devstack pike on my Ubuntu 16.04 by following this link:
https://www.mirantis.com/blog/how-to-install-openstack-on-your-local-machine-using-devstack/.

when i tried to create an instance i got No sql_connection parameter is established as an error.

I've checked /etc/nova/nova.conf and database configuration was as following:

[database]
connection = mysql+pymysql://root:mypassword@127.0.0.1/nova_cell0?charset=utf8

[api_database]
connection = mysql+pymysql://root:mypassword@127.0.0.1/nova_api?charset=utf8

Besides i didn't find where the logs related to openstack are located. I only accessed to /opt/stack/logs/stack.sh.log and it doesn't any process.

How can i resolve this issue?
I'll be grateful if someone could help me resolving it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on Devstack Pike when I wanted to create a VM (from a HOT template) connecting it to an already existing network (**public**, which exists by default.)
(You can set up networking for a VM in (at least) 2 ways: either connect a port to it, or connect the VM to an existing network. In the latter case a port is implicitly created.)

The problem was that **public** belonged to another project.

When I specified a network that belonged to the same project, it was successful.

I hope this helps.

Edit: Btw, the Devstack logs go into the syslog.