# Error: No sql_connection parameter is established when creating VM instance on openstack pike devstack

Tags: mysql, cloud, openstack

I have setup an openstack by following [tutorial](https://www.udemy.com/course/deep-dive-the-openstack-cloud/). I am facing error on creating vm instance.
The error is:
[image: error]

I have configured the sql following this [link](https://docs.openstack.org/mitaka/install-guide-ubuntu/nova-controller-install.html)
My nova.conf file looks like this:
[image: nova.conf]

Note: I am not connecting the vm to public network as given in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48648094/error-no-sql-connection-parameter-is-established-when-creating-instances-on-ope)

Comment: Just so you know, the tutorial can't be seen by anyone who hasn't purchased the Udemy course. Furthermore, are you sure your config file is read?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when
`connection = mysql+pymysql://nova:NOVA_DBPASS@controller/nova`
is not exist in `[database]` part in /etc/nova/nova.conf.

If the `NOVA_DBPASS` is wrong, then the error message will be
`Unable to establish connection to http://controller:8774/v2.1/servers/detail: HTTPconnectionPool`, not the `no sql_connection parameter is established`.

After setting the nova.conf config file, you should restart the nova service with these commands.

`service nova-api restart`
`service nova-scheduler restart`
`service nova-conductor restart`
`service nova-novncproxy restart`